# How to set NULL in all keys of array which aren't defined?

Tags: php, arrays, null

I have a PHP code like this:

```
$var = "
         <ul>
               <li class='".$this->data['active']['one']."'></li>
               <li class='".$this->data['active']['two']."'></li>
               <li class='".$this->data['active']['three']."'></li>
               <li class='".$this->data['active']['four']."'></li>
               <li class='".$this->data['active']['five']."'></li>
         </ul>
       ";
```

Always one key of this array `data['active']` is defined. I mean is sometimes only this is defined:

- `$this->data['active']['one']`

And sometimes only this:

- `$this->data['active']['two']`

And so on ..! I want to say, I'm always faced with a lot of this kind of notice:

> **Notice:** Undefined index: three in {path} on line {x}

---

Well, How can I set null to all other keys of that array? I did that like this (but it doesn't work)

```
$this->data['active'][] = null;
$this->data['active']['one'] = 'classname'; // or ['two'] or ['three'] and so on
```

Again, just one of those array is fill *(defined)*. Ok well, is there any solution to I remove that **Notice:** ?

Comment: (!empty($this->data['active']['one']) ? $this->data['active']['one'] : "null")

Comment: It would be easier to define them all with NULL then overwrite the one you want to have a value.

Comment: `$keys = ['one','two','three','four','five']; $defaults = array_fill($keys, null); $this->data['active'] = array_merge($this->data['active'], $defaults);`

Comment: side note: php 7 introduced the [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/de/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) -> `$this->data['active']['one'] ?? 'null'`

Comment: Thank you all guys. I have another small and related question @MarkBaker: This line is correct in php? `$var = $_SESSION['id'];`. I mean is that session is fill just when user is logged, Now I want to know, should I check that session and if exists then assignment or don't need to that checking?

Comment: It's a perfectly valid line in the right context, but it will still throw out warnings if you haven't started a session, or if you don't have an id value in session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways - perhaps something like this would simplify things:

Effectively you need to check that the key exists in the array before trying to use it in any way - the function `ke` is shorthand for `key exists` and uses the `array_key_exists` function to check that the specified key is available otherwise it returns a default empty string.

```
<?php

    $active=$this->data['active'];

    function ke( $a, $k ){
        return array_key_exists( $k, $a ) ? $a[ $k ] : '';  
    }

    $var = "
             <ul>
                   <li class='".ke( $active, 'one' )."'></li>
                   <li class='".ke( $active, 'two' )."'></li>
                   <li class='".ke( $active, 'three' )."'></li>
                   <li class='".ke( $active, 'four' )."'></li>
                   <li class='".ke( $active, 'five' )."'></li>
             </ul>
           ";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the key is setted or a foreach to each element:

```
 $var = "<li class='". (isset($this->data['active']['one']) ? $this->data['active']['one'] : '')."'></li>    
<li class='". (isset($this->data['active']['two']) ? $this->data['active']['two'] : '')."'></li>    
<li class='". (isset($this->data['active']['three']) ? $this->data['active']['three'] : '')."'></li>";
```

or

```
foreach($this->data['active'] as $key => $value){
    $var .= "<li class='" . $value . "'></li>";
}
```